# window scroll to detect footer animation

Tags: jquery, animation, scrolltop

I'm trying to get my footer to animate in when the user scrolls down but then animates out when the user scrolls to the top.

My code seems to work for the footer to animate in when you scroll down but not when you return to the top.

Also, I'm trying to set it to animate once you scroll 400 px down from the top but for some reason the animate happens the moment you scroll.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()<400){
        $("#footer").animate({"bottom" : "0px"}, 3000);
    }else if($(window).scrollTop()>400){
        $("#footer").animate({"bottom" : "-150px"}, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

All help welcome.

Comment: Is the $("#footer").animate({"bottom" : "0px"}, 3000); showing or hiding the footer?

Comment: It's showing the footer at 0px and taking the footer out of view at -150 px.

Comment: Just been messing around with the script and removed the `else if` statement and just used `else`. I can't get onto JS fiddle but it seems to work in W3 schools "try it yourself" code boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you say

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop()<400){
      $("#footer").animate({"bottom" : "0px"}, 3000);
```

According to your comment above opx shows the footer. So this means that the footer will animate as soon as the user starts to scrolls and the distances scrolled is less than 400 pixels. Which is: the first moment you start to scroll. That is why the footer is shown at the first moment you scroll. I think you need to do this:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()<400){
        $("#footer").stop().animate({"bottom" : "-150px"}, 3000);
    }else {
        $("#footer").stop().animate({"bottom" : "0px"}, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I got as far as removing the `if else` statement but just to reverse the footer positions worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: mind the extra .stop() calls. They make sure any current animation is stopped immediately. IT looks better that way\